# What would happen if nerves didn't have refractory period?

Tags: neuroanatomy, central-nervous-system, peripheral-nervous-system

What would happen if nerves didn't have refractory period? And, what part of his nervous system or neurons are not needed?

Comment: Who is "his"? Are you talking about a human neurologic system in general?

Comment: Yes it is a scenario case.

Comment: Is this a homework question? If so, you may want to check this out on the help page... http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework

Comment: Are you asking about the theoretical implication in terms of the function of neural system? Clearly this is not a biophysically plausible scenario since it will allow infinite number of action potentials in a finite time.

Answer (score 0):

Refractory period returns the repolarization period to the nerve's resting potential . it's the time taken for recovery of a neuron to generate another impulse being excited by another stimulus . so if nerve doesn't have refractory period they wouldn't be able to return to its resting potential & generate new impulse . moreover the repolarization potential further exceeds its value and cause hyperpolarization , so its badly necessary to restore to resting potential by expelling na+ and taking k+ in . unless it would be impossible to restore the resting potential & be ready to get excited to transmit another impulse via the electrochemical pathway . one more benefit of refractory period is that it causes unidirectional impulse conduction.
I didn't get the 2nd part of your question. What are you trying to mean , make it more clear.

Comment: Nice answer, but since you are a new user, you should give some source/reference for the answer.